# How to decode array of bytes by G.729, G.723 etc ...?

Tags: c#, voip, decode, rtp, codec

I have an **RTP** connection, and i can extract all *Payload* parts and concat them to each other sequentially to a **byte array**.

How can i *decode* this array?(suppose that i know the codec)
Is there any library that *implements* voip codecs?

Language: C#

Answer (score 0):

Check out FFMPEG library.

```
www.ffmpeg.org/ 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to do just that and haven't been able using ffmpeg.  I did a quick search and found this:  http://www.codeforge.com/article/39270